# Why does not work routing with regular expression in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following URL:

http://test.com/news

Where `http://test.com/` is a base URL.

`news` is controller.

For this URL there is route:

```
$route['news'] = "news/index";
```

I need that to work this URL:

```
http://test.com/en/news
```

For this I tried routing rule:

```
$route['(\S{2})/news'] = "news/index";
$route['(^\S+)/news'] = "news/index";
$route['^(\S+)/news'] = "news/index";
```

But It does not work

Comment: `(\S{2})/news` should work, so I'm guessing some other (previously defined) route matches that URI and this regular expression never gets executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a specific reason you are using regular expressions that I am unaware of, you can accomplish what you are after with the following route:

```
$route['(:any)/news'] = "news/index";
```